# Maximum Likelyhood(Cut_off)

Tags: python, data-science

I tried to find, cut-off where 'sensitivity' + 'specificity' is higher
but I found there are more than one cut-off, and all these cut-off are not significant for the classification.

```
test_roc_like_df = pd.DataFrame()
test_temp = hr_test_predict.copy()

for cut_off in np.linspace(0,1,80):
    test_temp['predicted'] = test_temp['prob'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x < cut_off else 1)
    test_temp['tp'] = test_temp.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['actual']==1 and x['predicted']==1 else 0, axis=1)
    test_temp['fp'] = test_temp.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['actual']==0 and x['predicted']==1 else 0, axis=1)
    test_temp['tn'] = test_temp.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['actual']==1 and x['predicted']==0 else 0, axis=1)
    test_temp['fn'] = test_temp.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['actual']==0 and x['predicted']==0 else 0, axis=1)
    sensitivity = test_temp['tp'].sum() / (test_temp['tp'].sum() + test_temp['fn'].sum())
    specificity = test_temp['tn'].sum() / (test_temp['tn'].sum() + test_temp['fp'].sum())
    test_roc_like_table = pd.DataFrame([cut_off, sensitivity, specificity]).T
    test_roc_like_table.columns = ['cutoff', 'sensitivity', 'specificity']
    test_roc_like_df = pd.concat([test_roc_like_df, test_roc_like_table], axis=0)

print(test_roc_like_df['total'].max())
print(test_roc_like_df[test_roc_like_df['total'] == test_roc_like_df['total'].max()])
```

I just want to find a single cut-off, which makes easy to take decision in classification.

Answer (score 0):

if you violated the boundary but did not reach the cutoff (!stop_cutoff && stop_bound),
evaluate at the boundary.